# How to remove keyrings in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, gnome-keyring

First question is what are keyrings in Ubuntu? And second question is how to disable them?

I am a beginner in Ubuntu and this thing is really annoying me. I have migrated from Windows 7 and don't have any idea about this.

Every time I login to the system it asks me to enter my keyrings. I don't know which password to introduce there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to Linux.

Here is a description of [Gnome keyrings](http://live.gnome.org/GnomeKeyring).

[This previous question](https://superuser.com/questions/43132/ubuntu-enter-password-for-default-keyring-to-unlock) may enable you to disable them or avoid reentering a password. I would read all the answers and see what works for you. You might also search superuser for "keyring" and see if another answer fits your situation better.

[This page](http://mexpolk.wordpress.com/2008/02/06/ubuntu-change-default-keyring-password/) describes how to reset the default keyring password in Ubuntu.

Comment: The problem is that I don't know old password of keyrings to disable them. I don't know which password to introduce their.

Comment: Try these directions. From the Ubuntu help system:
You may be asked for a password every time you log in so that you can connect to a network. You can stop this from happening like so:
   1.  Right click the Network Manager icon and choose Edit Connections.            
   2. Go to the Wireless tab, select the connection you are using and click Edit.       
   3. Check Available to all users and click Apply. Enter your password when asked.            
The next time you log in, you should not need to enter your password in order to connect to your network connection.