# How to remove Chrome login keyring requirement in Ubuntu 18.04 via command line

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, google-chrome, bash, gnome-keyring

> I'm writing some bash scripts to set up an Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (Bionic Beaver) environment

As described in [this question](https://superuser.com/q/43132/1063603), I've been prompted with an *unlock your login keyring* request every first time I open Google Chrome application:

[image]

There's yet other questions about this subjects through SE Forums, however most answered with GUI solutions. For instance:

1. [Why do I need to enter a password for the Default Keyring to unlock?](https://superuser.com/q/157175/1063603)
2. [How can I stop being prompted to unlock the 'default' keyring on boot?](https://askubuntu.com/q/867/689894)
3. [How do I change the “Default” password](https://askubuntu.com/q/25974/689894)
4. [Why Chrome always ask for keyring and is it possible to remove it without giving password?](https://askubuntu.com/q/884897/689894)

So far, [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/884903/689894) suggestion of change application's launcher `Exec` line was the closest to be done via command line.

However I'm looking for someway of manage this in the appropriate setting.
I'll appreciate some help!

Comment: What do you mean by "manage this in the appropriate setting"?