# How to skip the 'Enter password to unlock your login keyring' in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, gnome-keyring

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ubuntu: “Enter Password for Default Keyring to Unlock”](https://superuser.com/questions/43132/ubuntu-enter-password-for-default-keyring-to-unlock)

Whenever I login to ubunutu, it prompts me a 'Enter password to unlock your login keyring'?

Is there anyway I can skip that dialog?

Thank you.

Comment: Use pam_keyring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been answered multiple times on superuser.

[Why do I need to enter a password for the Default Keyring to unlock?](https://superuser.com/questions/43132/ubuntu-enter-password-for-default-keyring-to-unlock)

Comment: Vote to close as duplicate is initiated.