# Completely stop gnome keyring popups

Tags: google-chrome, fedora, passwords, gnome, gnome-keyring

After some updates to fedora in the last few years, I've been getting the following popups (one when I login and one when ever I start `google-chrome`)...

*"Choose password for new keyring"*
*"An application wants access to create a new keyring called 'Default'. Choose the password you want to use for it."*
[image]

(If I've then created "Default")
*"Enter password for keyring 'Default' to unlock"*
*"An application wants access to the keyring 'Default', but it is locked."*
[image]

I don't want to use a password manager and would like to never have these popups. **How can I remove or disable them? I do not have root access**, so I'll need some kind of per-user config I can set.

Many related questions assume I'm using ubuntu, e.g.: [Why do I need to enter a password for the Default Keyring to unlock?](https://superuser.com/questions/43132/why-do-i-need-to-enter-a-password-for-the-default-keyring-to-unlock), and I haven't found anything that works for fedora.

Comment: the ultimate solution is  rm -f /usr/share/.local/keyrings/* then remove or  disable gnome-keyring  from packages however if this is only at boot and chrome launch this  lends me to believe you are backgrounding chrome and it is asking for 1 of 2 reasons.  1) chrome is NOT saving the config in the singleton cookie  OR 2) for some reason gnome-keyring is not properly saving it.

Answer (score 2):

Setting this keyring to blank should let it do its thing without bothering you. If you have already set it up, trash your keyring and restart Chrome to receive the fresh prompt (where you can set it to not use a password).

Check the following locations for the keychain:

- `~/.gnome2/keyrings/default.keyring`
- `~/.local/share/keyrings/*`

More elaboration and links at [my Unix SE post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/324843/42894).